# How do I send out an update for my custom wordpress theme?

Tags: theme-development, themes, updates, automatic-updates

I created a wordpress theme and I've installed it on two sites so far. I recently made an update to the theme and I want to push it to all of my clients. How do I send out an update?

Comment: did you include an updater mechanism in your theme? If you did not, then the answer is that there is no way to show an update for that theme in the updates section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I send out an update?

Unless you took the time to find and implement an update server mechanism into your theme, you'll have to manually distribute the updated theme to your clients.

It should be enough to send out a standard WP theme zip, and for them to upload it. If it has the same folder name WordPress will replace your theme with the newer version from the zip file.

Additionally, you can use one of literally hundreds of other methods to replace the theme folder:

- import it with WP CLI
- overwrite it in FTP
- overwrite it via shell commands
- Git/SVN version control!
- Composer upgrades
- etc etc etc

All of these options are highly dependent on your unique situation, the methods you took to install the theme in the first place, and the access/tooling available

Comment: note that I did mention if you had implemented an update server mechanism, but I did not share any mechanisms. This is because there is no correct answer, just lots and lots of competing libraries, products, and services, and many many ways to do it all with their own tradeoffs and complexities, none are more correct than the other. I also don't want to write an answer that will be out of date within days of writing it, especially when a quick google reveals hundreds of options

Comment: Hey Tom, thanks for responding. I wouldnt mind implementing a server option but i tried google searching for a way to do it and didnt really know what to google. It gave me a bunch of links that show how to update instead of how to implement a server option. If you could supply anything it would be helpful. Anyways, thanks again. This is super helpful.